# Teracopy not copying all selected files and folders, only one

Tags: windows-10, teracopy

I've installed teracopy on a fresh Win10 Install. I've opened it and selected it as the default copy manager. I've even restarted.

When I select 7 folders to copy, teracopy charts all files in the folders.

However then in ONLY copies the one folder I dragged over, and ignores all other selected files and folders. I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem with version=3.10,

Try installing the previous version=3.9.7 of TeraCopy that has been my solution, however this is a temporary fix, as it is better to use the current version.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen, I am reading it as the solution is to use 3.9.7